# Convert XML to plain old JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, object

Given this sample XML:

```
  <patient>
    <name>
      <given>Bob</given>
      <family>Dole</family>
    </name>
  </patient>
```

I would like to create an object, `patient` and be able to do something like `alert(patient.name.given)` and get a popup that says "Bob".  My actual data is much more complex than this so I would also need to account for attributes and arrays.

How can this be achieved?

I'm currently using `parseXML()` but I'd rather not have to type `alert($xml.find("patient").find("name").find("given").text)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix#parse-xml-into-js) of how to use [JSONIX](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) to parse (unmarshal) XML into JavaScript:

### Parse XML into JS

```
// Include or require PO.js so that PO variable is available
// For instance, in node.js:
var PO = require('./mappings/PO').PO;

// First we construct a Jsonix context - a factory for unmarshaller (parser)
// and marshaller (serializer)
var context = new Jsonix.Context([PO]);

// Then we create a unmarshaller
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

// Unmarshal an object from the XML retrieved from the URL
unmarshaller.unmarshalURL('po.xml',
    // This callback function will be provided
    // with the result of the unmarshalling
    function (unmarshalled) {
        // Alice Smith
        console.log(unmarshalled.value.shipTo.name);
        // Baby Monitor
        console.log(unmarshalled.value.items.item[1].productName);
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is `PO`?  It looks like something generated by a java utility.  Is that required?  I don't have a schema or xsd

Comment: Yes, Java is required to generate mappings automatically from an XSD, but you can also generate them manually if you don't have an XSD or Java.  See [Mapping XML to JavaScript Objects](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Mapping-XML-to-JavaScript-Objects)

Comment: I don't understand why I *have* to generate or manually create a mapping. I really just want an object that mirrors the XML.

Comment: A mapping merely defines what you mean by *mirrors the XML*.

Comment: If the XML file is `<document><person><name>` then that's what I mirrored. Why do I have to create a mapping that says `document { person { name {} } }`??